# Activity does not have an options menu

Tags: android, robolectric

I was trying to simulate click on **Menu Item** present in **Toolbar** using **Robolectric**, using the following code

```
ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);
shadowActivity.clickMenuItem(R.id.action_logout);
```

But it is giving me an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Activity does not have an options menu! Did you forget to call super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
```

Code of the Activity:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_layout);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    setToolbarIcons();
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_splash);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_logout){
        //Doing Some task here...
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Could you please help me with the Error?

Comment: Could you please post the code of your ShadowActivity

Comment: can you see the code of the activity?

Comment: Is this your whole activity? Is there only the `onCreate` Method? Where is toolbar initialized?

Comment: The toolBar initialized using this code. ButterKnife.bind(this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that you do not set your toolbar as the supportActionbar/ActionBar.

I have never seen such a toolbar-inflation but normally it is done like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.toolbar) Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);            
        butterKnife.bind(this);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actions_myactivity, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //handle clicked menuItem

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

As your error is :

```
Activity does not have an options menu!
```

Also the Testmethod should look like this

```
@Test
public void clickOnMenuItem(){
    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);
    Menu menu =  mToolbar.getMenu();
    shadowActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    shadowActivity.clickMenuItem(R.id.action_logout);
}
```

I think this is the way to go!

Comment: Thanks  for your response @Altoyr. But my Activity is extending the fragment activity, so I was not  able to apply setSupportActionBar(toolbar); thats why I choose that way.

Comment: You should extend your activity from AppCompatActivity not FragmentActivity

Comment: Thanks @Altoyr. I try this.

Comment: hi ! I did whatever you have told but still I am getting the same Error

Comment: I can do some further research when I get home after work.

Comment: Thanks for your time, But I did some research and got a solution which is working fine, I will post it in the answer section.

Comment: You should also accept your anwser if it is working.

Comment: Yeah I tried but it is saying that I can accept My answer after 2 days

Answer (score 1):

After doing the changes in my **Activity** class and digging in **Robolectric** and **ToolBar** I made some changes in the test class too, which is working fine

```
@Test
public void clickOnMenuItem(){
    ShadowActivity shadowActivity = Shadows.shadowOf(activity);
    Menu menu =  mToolbar.getMenu();
    shadowActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    shadowActivity.clickMenuItem(R.id.action_logout);
}
```

Comment: You should not link to my answer, yours should "stand on its own"... I have added your test method to my answer to provide a full solution for future visitors

Comment: Okay, Sorry for that, I will change it